# Is there a way to determine how many CPU cycles my single-threaded program requires to execute?

Tags: cpu-cycles

I have a single-threaded, computationally intensive program and I would like to know if there is a way (such as a tool/profiler) that I can use to determine the **number of CPU cycles** my program requires to execute.